# Moving meteor app source code brokes the app

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am trying to create new Meteor app in the root folder of my current project. **I am trying to create new scaffolded Meteor app in already existing folder containing Git**.

Here is the first state after generating new Meteor app:

```
root_folder
- new_meteor_folder
-- meteor_source_codes
```

In this state app is running without any problem.
Then I move Meteor source codes to project root folder (including `.meteor`) and run again.

```
root_folder
- meteor_source_codes
```

But I gent an error: https://gist.github.com/pavelbinar/9cc8b028c6689d945996

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had new Meteor app source code with some previous `.js` file in same folder. Meteor then took that old file and included into project which caused the crash.